# Devart DotConnect got unexpected long decimal point for me while using entity framework 6 against Oracle

Tags: c#, entity-framework, decimal-point, devart, dotconnect

I have a record which contain a number in certain field: `25.99`. Whenever I select this record using Devart DotConnect from my C# code it returns me `25.990000000000002`. Therefore, my update statement prompt me such exception: `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

My code snippet is stated as follow:

```
var busRoutes = (
    from route in ctx.RMBUSROUTEs
    select route
).ToArray();

foreach (var busRoute in busRoutes)
{
    busRoute.LASTUPDDATE = DateTime.Now;
}

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

There are ~ only 100 records inside this table. Most of the records contains decimal number in that field while only a specific certain record always retrieve `25.99` as `25.990000000000002`. I am sure that the record value stored in DB is `25.99`. How come?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: what data type is it? because if it is float or double (which i would bet on), you better re-read on the properties of floating point numbers. the TL;DR is: never expect them to be precise, because they aren't.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann  programming type is double and db type is number(5, 2). This field is my primary key, if they aren't precise then how can I update records in this table?    EF can never help me to match record then...

Comment: double as primary key is a horrible idea. you should never do that. especially since floating point numbers aren't precise. either use a synthetic ID (int or guid, in a pinch string), or at least change it to decimal.

Comment: (also, on the assumption that `25.99` is a bus route number or something: here, `string` is actually the weapon of choice. numeric data types are for numbers - if it doesn't make sense to, for example, _add_ two values, it's not a numeric value - even if it consists of digits.)

Comment: As @FranzGleichmann said, it is better not to use double as a primary key. The provider-specific conversions are described at https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=16114#p175435.

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann and Devart . For those who come into this question and mutating your table schema is not a solution, you may try to change the mapping entity from float/double to decimal. You may find how decimal resolve this problem from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: @mannok maybe you could write an answer yourself with your solution, so whoever searches for the same problem in the future can find it more easily? (plus: i also like the https://floating-point-gui.de/ )

Answer (score -2):

Try to change type of **LASTUPDDATE** from *DateTime* to *string*. I dont know why, but it worked for me.

Comment: a) this answer has very low quality overall. b) it does not address the problem described in the question. c) answers based on "i don't know why" are never a good idea. we're not here to blindly guess, but to provide knowledge. please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)